# How to do mod_rewrite for a url with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Given that i have the following url in my site: **http://localhost/test/example.php?a=1&b=2**

How can i specify a redirect rule in my .htaccess file, such that this url is called when i enter the following in my browser:  **http://localhost/test/example/1.html**

In other words, if a user enters the url: ***http://localhost/test/example/1.html***, he should be displayed the page: ***http://localhost/test/example.php?a=1&b=2***

I have tried the following mod_rewrite code in my .htaccess file, but it does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+).html /example.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA]
```

This is the code in my **.htaccess** file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /example.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA]
```

Note: I am using WAMP2.0, Apache 2.2.6 and PHP 5.2.5

Comment: where is second parameter `b` in rewrited URL?

Comment: I don't need second parameter in the rewrited url.. i just need the first parameter, followed by a html extension.

Comment: Have you turned the rewrite engine on?

Comment: Yes, i have edited my question, adding the code in my .htaccess file

Comment: Put this in your example.php to help you debug `<?php echo $_GET['a'].$_GET['b']; ?>`

Comment: I already had that code in example.php, and it is showing the result as 12, if i go to the url: *http://localhost/test/example.php?a=1&b=2*. But i want to show the same output if i go to the url: *http://localhost/test/example/1.html*

Comment: The URL `localhost/test/example/1.html` doesn't contain both the values: `1` and `2` so how could you output them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you have an error in your rule, you must remove the slash at the beggining :

```
RewriteRule ^test/example/([0-9]+)\.html? /test/example.php?a=$1&b=2 [QSA]
```

Comment: you should now that this rule will transform http://localhost/test/example/1.html into http://example?a=test&b=example, is this what you are trying to do ? if yes what error are you getting exactly ?

Comment: No, i am not trying to do that. What i am trying to do is: Mod Redirect the url: *http://localhost/test/example.php?a=1&b=2* into *http://localhost/test/example/1.html*

Comment: then your rule is completly wrong, I edited my answer (but where do you get the number 2 from ? if you don't specify it in localhost/test/example/1.html)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16636/discussion-between-dskanth-and-yazmat)

Comment: Finally i could achieve what i wanted, with this rewrite rule:
*RewriteRule ^example/([^/]+)\.html? /test/example.php?a=$1 [QSA]*

Comment: Ok then the b param you didn't need it :o